# Strange function in Disassembly (IDA)

Tags: ida, disassembly

I was reversing one executable in IDA and found out the function with this structure:

```
.text:0058A6E0 sub_58A6E0      proc near               
.text:0058A6E0
.text:0058A6E0 var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:0058A6E0
.text:0058A6E0                 push    ecx
.text:0058A6E1                 mov     ecx, ds:SHAppBarMessage
.text:0058A6E7                 mov     eax, offset loc_612BC0
.text:0058A6EC                 or      eax, offset loc_612BBA
.text:0058A6F1                 or      eax, offset loc_612BB4
.text:0058A6F6                 or      eax, offset loc_612BAE
.text:0058A6FB                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058A6FD                 mov     ecx, ds:ShellExecuteW
.text:0058A703                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058A705                 mov     ecx, ds:SHGetFileInfoW
.text:0058A70B                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058A70D                 mov     ecx, ds:VariantInit
.text:0058A713                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058A715                 mov     ecx, ds:VariantClear
.text:0058A71B                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058A71D                 mov     ecx, ds:VariantCopy
.text:0058A723                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058A725                 mov     ecx, ds:VariantCopyInd
.text:0058A72B                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058A72D                 mov     ecx, ds:VariantChangeType
...

Lots of different functions.

...
.text:0058B8B8                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058B8BA                 mov     ecx, ds:RegCloseKey
.text:0058B8C0                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058B8C2                 mov     ecx, ds:RegOpenKeyExW
.text:0058B8C8                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058B8CA                 mov     ecx, ds:RegQueryValueExW
.text:0058B8D0                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058B8D2                 mov     ecx, dword_617AC4
.text:0058B8D8                 or      eax, offset loc_6129F8
...
Repeating simillar stuff
...
.text:0058B8F6                 or      eax, offset loc_6129D4
.text:0058B8FB                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058B8FD                 mov     ecx, [esp+4+var_4]
.text:0058B901                 or      eax, offset loc_6129CE
.text:0058B906                 or      eax, offset loc_6129C8
...
Repeating simillar stuff
...
.text:0058B938                 or      eax, offset loc_61298C
.text:0058B93D                 or      eax, offset loc_612986
.text:0058B942                 or      eax, ecx
.text:0058B944                 pop     ecx
.text:0058B945                 retn
.text:0058B945 sub_58A6E0      endp
```

I have tried to find what it is and why it was used, but I found literally nothing about it. It's not the first time I see similar function, so I really want to know what is it. It doesn't make any sense for me and simply abusing the imports. Thank you.

UPD: There is a hex values for some part of this function.

```
C1 8B 0D 20 65 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D 1C 65 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D 18 65 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D 14 65 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D 10 65 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D 0C 65 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D 08 65 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D 04 65 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D 00 65 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D FC 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D F8 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D F4 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D F0 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D EC 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D E8 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D E4 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D E0 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D DC 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D D8 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D D4 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D D0 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D CC 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D C8 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D C4 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D C0 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D BC 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D B8 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D B4 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D B0 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D AC 64 61 00 0B
C1 8B 0D A8 64 61 00 0B  C1 8B 0D A4 64 61 00 0B
```

Comment: can you show raw bytes?

Comment: Do you mean hex values?

Comment: yes, to see if those opcodes could be something else than code and IDA assuming them as code does it incorrectly.

Comment: Sadly, I can't find it. I have downloaded many malware samples to reverse and I can't realize which one it was. All I know, that function sub_58A6E0 was referenced once or twice, so it did not look like a loading functions by offsets.

Comment: I have updated the post with the hex input from the function. This is the ```or      eax, ecx``` and ```mov     ecx, ds:"function"``` repeated. I hope it can help.

Comment: is `ecx` initialized before calling this function?

Comment: I found nothing really meaningful in ```ecx``` before the function call. And as I see this function stored ```ecx``` in stack and returned it back in the end, so it was used just for ``or``` and ```mov``` operations.

Comment: Actually, var_4 is accessing the saved ecx which is why I was curious. Is var_4 written to somewhere else?

Comment: I have checked it and looks like it is a stack offset, also IDA shows it in the beginning of the function ```var_4 = dword ptr -4``` I have copied.